# Array type 'float [3]' is not assignable .Copying 2d Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, memcpy

I have the following code below:

```
typedef struct
 {
   float K[6][3]; //Kalman gain ([row][column])
 } FilterData;

void setFilterData(const FilterData *filterdata)
{
  FilterData r;
  int i;
  int i1; 
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < 6; i1++) {
      r.K[i1 + 6 * i] = filterdata->K[i + 3 * i1];
    }
  }
}
```

Compiling this code leads to the following error:

```
setFilterData.c: In function setFilterData :
setFilterData.c:25:23: error: assignment to expression with array type
       r.K[i1 + 6 * i] = filterdata->K[i + 3 * i1];
```

What is the alternative here?

Using memcpy explicitly also did not help.

```
FilterData r;  
int i;  
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   memcpy(r.K + (3*i),filterdata->K + i,sizeof(float) );
   memcpy(r.K + (3*i + 1),filterdata->K + (i+6),sizeof(float));
   memcpy(r.K + (3*i + 2),filterdata->K + (i+12),sizeof(float));
  
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to transpose the elements? Why do you have `i1 + 6 * i` and `i + 3 * i1`? How do you expect to put elements transposed from a 6×3 matrix into another 6×3 matrix instead of a 3×6 matrix?

Comment: (You do not need to write “I have the following code below:”. In this context, “following,” “below,” and “:” all mean the same thing, that there is stuff after this. You can just write “I have this code:”.)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the `FilterData.K` is defined as a 2-dimensional array, but `setFilterData()` is treating it as if it were a 1-dimensional array.

The minimual fix is to say

```
r.K[i1][i] = filterData.K[i1][i]
```

(this assumes the transposition in your original code is a bug, not a feature, I'll have to read more about Kalman gain to know)

But there's no reason to double for-loop and assign each member separately. You could

```
memcpy(&r, filterData, sizeof(r))
```

or better yet

```
r = *filterData
```

Answer (score 1):

`r.K` is a two-dimensional array.  This means that `r.K[n]` is a `float` array of length 3.  You can't assign a value to an array.  For example, ask yourself what

```
int A[5];
A = 6;
```

would mean.  If you want to assign a few to a specific location inside a two-dimensional (or multi-dimensional) array, you have to specify all of the indices.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < 6; i1++) {
        r.K[i1][i] = ... // I'm not sure what you actually want here.
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you cannot assign the array is the *last 5 words in* [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: “class, the behavior is undefined”?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `"and is not an lvalue"` (sorry, last 5 words in next to last sentence `:)`